# Trouble with the Deno plugin for IntelliJ, auto import, import completion, type hints

Tags: intellij-idea, deno

I am not sure if the plugin works differently for Webstorm. I am using it in intelliJ, and feel that this plugin is not working according to [this post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/06/deno-support-in-jetbrains-ides/).

To name a few:

1. I don't see auto imports. I type `assertEquals` and have `asserts.ts` from standard lib cached, but the IDE treats this symbol like plain text, without any contextual actions available on it, like **go to definition** or **find usage**, no prompt for **import from ...** either.
2. After I manually import the symbol `assertEquals`, putting `import { assertEquals } from "https://deno.land/std@0.79.0/testing/asserts.ts";` on top, I can't see its signature like normal imported typescript functions, nor can I `cmd+b` and go to where it is defined. The hashed file name for modules makes it difficult to find the source file :(, so IDE's documentation prompt becomes very necessary.
3. I can't remember the full url, and the plugin has no aid on that front. Even the module is cached before, there is no auto completion when I am typing that `import` statement.

One more thing.
I don't see where I can alter the behaviors or see what is possible for the plugin. In the setting page of this plugin, all it has is a checkbox to enable/disable this plugin.

Could someone please share some information about properly using this plugin, or what is the progress on the compatibility between Deno and intelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-import for external Deno modules is not yet supported, please follow [WEB-48412](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48412) and [WEB-48411](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48411) for updates